# Image media is creating a new image size of 768px but how do I stop it?

Tags: wordpress, image, media, image-size

After updating to WordPress 4.5 I was doing a media upload test and I noticed that I was generating a new image size that I cannot figure out how to stop.

The current function I am using to prevent generating multiple sizes of my media is:

```
function add_image_insert_override( $sizes ) {
    unset( $sizes[ 'thumbnail' ]);
    unset( $sizes[ 'medium' ]);
    unset( $sizes[ 'large' ]);
    unset( $sizes[ 'full' ] );
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'add_image_insert_override' );
```

How can I stop WordPress 4.5 from generating images with a width of 768px?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't find this anywhere other than the article I referenced under [Responsive Images in WordPress 4.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/) when they indicated that a new image size had been created:

> A new default intermediate size, `medium_large`, has been added to
>   better take advantage of responsive image support. The new size is
>   768px wide by default, with no height limit, and can be used like any
>   other size available in WordPress. As it is a standard size, it will
>   only be generated when new images are uploaded or sizes are
>   regenerated with third party plugins.

After reading this article I was then able to update my function to:

```
function add_image_insert_override( $sizes ){
    unset( $sizes[ 'thumbnail' ]);
    unset( $sizes[ 'medium' ]);
    unset( $sizes[ 'medium_large' ] );
    unset( $sizes[ 'large' ]);
    unset( $sizes[ 'full' ] );
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'add_image_insert_override' );
```

Now when I add media to a post I am no longer generating `foobar-768xwhatever`.  Hope this helps the next person.

Comment: Works like a charm. I expanded a bit on it - if it's of any use to anyone:
https://io.bikegremlin.com/5872/optimization-05-pictures/#3.4